# Change Fragment name in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Hello I have Implemented a activity where i used navigation drawer.Its work fine but sometimes app is crashing because of actionbar.it throw nullpointerexception

I called fragment as follows

Comment: post the crash's stack trace

Comment: Sorry sir i dont have crash report right now.because it throw exception at rare condition

Comment: parent.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
At this line i get null pointer exception when come back from other activity

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `getActivity` from `onCreateView`, as it may return `null`, if the `Activity` isn't attached yet to the `Fragment`.

`Activities` and `Fragments` have separate lifecycles, `getActivity` can be null while your fragment is in process of preparation.

You can move your code that depends on `getActivity` to the [Fragment.onActivityCreated(Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) callback.
Note that it is called after `onCreateView`.

See more info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CoordinatingWithActivity

UPDATE:
As requested, here's a fixed code - I just split some of your onCreateView method into onActivityCreated

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    person = new Person();
    str = person.getFragment();
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_list, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());
    parent = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        title = getArguments().getString("Title");
        if (title != null) {
            parent.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sir could you please tell me the changes to change fragment title

Comment: i am not getting what you said.could you please make changes in my code